# Please help me perform DC analysis of the attached circuit and derive equation for VB (Q1)

Tags: dc, differential, analysis

I am designing a differential pair with single supply source (Vcc), and I am very particular about not using split supply. I am using discrete current source for setting the tail current, and biasing the Q1 and Q2 using R4 and R5. To determine their values, I must know VB at Q1, which is sum of Vbe(Q1), VR1 and Vc(Q6) (w.r.t. GND). I am finding it difficult to calculate Vc(Q6) in such an arrangement. Please help me with this difficult arrangement.  [image]

Comment: But you have drawn the circuit already in a circuit simulator, why don't you run the simulation and see the result?

Comment: Just press the analyse button!!

Comment: It looks like there may be something odd about the connections to the bases of some of your transistors. Some of them show a junction dot, suggesting that the wire extends beyond the connection point. Fix that, then run a simulation. Let SPICE do the heavy lifting.

Comment: One hint : You'll need to know (or make assumptions about) hfe in Q1.

Comment: @Elliot, Justme, Andy : Yes, I did run the simulation, but i need to derive the equations of VCE (Q1) and VCE(Q6) for analysis purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need the equation if simulation will give you the answer? Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @Amit You are asking for equations and have not provided any at all on your own. Not a single one. That's striking, to me. Normally, one would provide as much as they can so that they show well where they are stuck. For example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1710840/323885) is a question I asked some years ago when I was stuck on an issue. Note the equations in my question? They clarify where I'm stuck. You've done nothing of the sort here. I don't even know how you calculated that ridiculous value for \$R_7\$! And it is crazy-minded. Please add your work product to your question.

Comment: @Elliot, It is not a homework problem. Starting from simulation is like mechanic, and starting from equations is engineering. Simple.

Comment: @Amit I think you will find that many of the contributors here are experienced and professional engineers. We know that you pick the right tool for the task at hand. We have developed an intuitive understanding of how things work...we don't need to write the equations anymore. A simulation will provide a much more accurate answer than your equations.

Comment: @Elliot, May be it is shortcoming of my personality type. :) I first like to derive system of equations and then work my way manually on the problem and then verify results with simulation. In this case, I have the equation, VCE(Q1) + VCE(Q6) = VCC-VBE(Q7) - Ic*R1- Ie_q6*R6. I also know that Ic and Ie will decide VCE drops across Q1 and Q2. Had it been single transistor, it was very easy, but it is not so clear on how to do I establish discrete relationship to individually calculate VCE(Q1) or VCE(Q6). I will keep working on it and will update here if any breakthrough found.

Answer (score 0):

Make R4 = R5 = 20k. Add two more 20k resistors, one from each of the bases of Q1 & Q2 to ground. Add two 10uF capacitors, one between each ac voltage source and the bases of Q1 & Q2 (positive of capacitors to bases). This will bias the bases of Q1 & Q2 to about mid-supply.

As the circuit stands:

CCS provides constant current of 0.7/500 = 1.4mA

This current is split equally between the two sides and so Ic of Q1 = 0.7mA

hFE of BC547B (at Ic = 2mA) is about 300 and so base current = 0.7mA/300 = 2.3uA

Voltage at base of Q1 = 9-(2.3uA * 1000k) = 6.7V

Voltage at base of Q2 will be about the same.

Comment: Thanks much. Your inputs helped me analyze it from alternate angle, i.e. from Ic to Ib and then Vb. I love this idea, but others, please share your views too... I would like to understand in such an arrangement, how does Vce Q1 equation looks like?

Comment: Vc of Q1 will always be equal to about 9V - 0.7V = 8.3V as Q7 is diode configured, Q7's base is always about 0.7V below 9V and its collector is connected to its base. The emitter of Q1 is always about 0.7V below its base voltage.

Comment: I suspect that the OP is asking for your help in answering a homework problem rather than actually designing a circuit.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my question. VCE across Q1 and Q6 is the matter of design time requirement and depends upon where you want to keep the VCE_Q for the differential amplifier (i.e. Q1 and Q2). So based on this, the way to design such a circuit with single voltage source is as follows:

1. Decide Ic_Q based on your application type, say 500microA, 1mA etc.
2. Design current source for 2*Ic_Q.
3. Assume VCE_Q6. say 1V or 2V.
4. VE_Q1 = VR1+VCE_Q6+VR6. i.e. VCE_Q1 = VCC - VBE_Q7 - VE_Q1.
5. R4 = [VCC-(VBE_Q1+VE_Q)]/(Ic_Q/Beta)

This is my first draft of the answer. I will update it to correct any gaps. This approach provided me second, third and fourth harmonics below -80dB.